# Upgrading to cloud database - MSDTC

Tags: database, web8.5, sql-server

Just reading the docs on upgrading to SDL Web 8.5, specifically [Content Manager database support history](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E542A740-2421-40B9-BEF1-68EE44AD598E&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E542A740-2421-40B9-BEF1-68EE44AD598E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E542A740-2421-40B9-BEF1-68EE44AD598E).

For cloud options like AWS & Azure, the docs mention *only if your implementation does not use MSDTC* - daft question, but how do you know if an implementation is using MSDTC or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Improved Cloud support](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-34B24945-6280-4533-AC9E-A4C81DB27726) page on the online docs:

> Such types of implementations include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Implementations that still use the Legacy Pack
> - Implementations containing code that interacts with the Core Service and uses transactions
> - Implementations containing extensions that connect to an external data source (say, a database)

If it helps to identify whether this is the case, there is a good question and answer about implementing WCF Transaction support using CoreService here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398027/how-can-i-implement-wcf-transaction-support-on-custom-class-using-coreservice

Comment: Thanks Jon. So if your upgrading from 2013 SP1, I assume the 2013 SP1 Content Manager server is using MSDTC - so other than that, you can upgrade to a cloud db as Web 8.5 Content Server no longer does?

Comment: Hi Neil. Yes, that is my understanding. As long as you're upgrading the Content Manager to Web 8.5 (and don't use any of the 'other' transactional stuff) then you should be fine to move to AWS / Azure.

Comment: That is correct, yes. If no legacy, no custom wcf jobs with transactions enabled, then you don't need msdtc